# $\sin(y/x)=\sqrt{3}/6$ solve for $y$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We have an equation $\sin(y/x)=\sqrt{3}/6$

How can we solve this equation for $y$?

What we have done in solution is :

$\sin(\pi—(y/x—2\pi)) = \sqrt{3}/6 $

And then we applied $\arcsin(x)$.

I dont understand what why we have done that.

Comment: You clearly can't solve for $y$, only for the ratio $y/x$. For that, simply take the $\arcsin$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\pi - (\frac{y}{x} - 2\pi)) = \sin(3\pi - \frac{y}{x}) = \sin(\pi - \frac{y}{x}) = \sin(\frac{y}{x})$  justifies the substitution.

It is not immediately clear to me why the solution does this substitution.

Possibly it is setting up to use $\sin(a - b)$ formulas to express the solution as a difference of known sine quantities so that you can apply simple trigonometric identities to find the solution by hand.

Comment: In the comments it says that it has something to do with the interval where arcsin is defined. But maybe they got it wrong I dont know

Comment: Is $\frac{y}{x}$ restricted to a certain domain?

Comment: The solution doesnt say